# Select Date range between two months

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My table has one `[date]` column and would like to filter dates between March to auguest for any year.

Here is my functions, but none of them work and returns all data.

```
iif(CDate([Date]) between DateAdd ("m",3, CDate([Date])) And DateAdd ("m",7,CDate([Date])),"1","0")


iif([Date of Activity] between (DatePart("m", [Date of Activity]) = 4) And (DatePart("m", [Date of Activity]) = 8),"1","0")
```

Comment: That doesn't look like MySQL. Why did you put tags for both `mysql` and `ms-access` in this question, they're not at all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date is a reserved word and should not be used for a field name. That said, the following should work if your field is a date/time field and not text. Month() Between 3 and 8